# Delete Record with WHERE clause

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my table:

```
id    t_id     min      max       range      name
1       2      2         6          2        Peter
2       2      3         5          3        Leofer
3       2      3         5          4        Josh
4       2      3         5          5        Sonny
5       2      2         6          6        Sammy
```

I want to delete the records for `Peter` and `Sammy`. Everything in this table consists of variable data, so using the column names would be the best solution.

Here is my code so far:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($pick); $x++ )
{
      $where = ('pick_range' < $pick[$x] && 'pick_range' > $pick[$x] );
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->where('teaser_id',$first_page_data['teaser_id']);
      $this->db->where('sb_id',$sbid);
      $this->db->where('pick_range ', $where);
      $query = $this->db->get('tbl_name');

      if($query->num_rows() == 1);
      {

        $this->db->where('pick_range',$where);
        $this->db->where('teaser_id',$first_page_data['teaser_id']);
        $query = $this->db->delete('tbl_name');

    }

}
```

Is there any other simple approach to do this?

Comment: If you want to delete record peter and sammy then why there is a loop and what is in `$pick` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($pick); $x++ )
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $where = ('pick_range' < $pick[$x] && 'pick_range' > $pick[$x] );
    //$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('teaser_id',$first_page_data['teaser_id']);
    $this->db->where('sb_id',$sbid);
    $this->db->where('pick_range ', $where);
    //$query = $this->db->get('tbl_name');

 //if($query->num_rows() == 1);
 //{

    $this->db->where('pick_range',$where);
    $this->db->where('teaser_id',$first_page_data['teaser_id']);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_name');
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return TRUE;

 //}

}
```

This will delete data that matches the `WHERE` clause.